# How to reallocate character pointer for concatenation?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, token, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote the function to tokenize the entire string and concatenate space and string length of each token . my functions is

main function

```
char *final_buff = NULL;

data_token(databuf,&final_buff);
```

after that I call

```
free(final_buff);
```

function:

```
int data_token(char *buffer,/*user_strinf*/
                    char **final_buff)/*store each token*/
{
    char *token_arr;
    char temp[10];
    int length = 0;
    token_arr = strtok(buffer,",");/*find first token*/
    while (token_arr != NULL)
    {
            printf("tokens--%s\n",token_arr);

            length = length + strlen(token_arr)+4;

            *final_buff = realloc(*final_buff,(length)*sizeof(char));/*allocate memory for the buffer*/

            if (NULL == *final_buff)
            {
                    printf("token memory allocation error\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            strcat(*final_buff,token_arr);/*concatinate the token to buffer*/
            strcat(*final_buff," ");
            sprintf(temp,"%d",strlen(token_arr));
            strcat(*final_buff,temp);       /*concatinate buffer with string length */
            strcat(*final_buff," ");
            token_arr = strtok(NULL , ",");/*read next token */
    }

    return 1;
   }
```

is this allocation will work when I calling this function . Because I am scared about how much length should I allocate when adding space and integer with that array . is it correct ? I got segmentation fault or core dumped .

Comment: char temp[20] is already defined in function

Comment: @CoolGuy it's initialized in the line above.

Comment: @mch , Oh , I missed that. My bad

Comment: the length is too small if `temp` contains more than 1 digit.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
strcat(*final_buff,token_arr);/*concatinate the token to buffer*/
```

will be a problem in the first iteration of the loop.

You are also assuming that the length of the string will never need more than 1 space. You can remove that assumption by executing

```
   sprintf(temp,"%d",strlen(token_arr));
```

early in the loop and using `strlen(temp)` to compute the length required for `*final_buff`.

I suggest the following update to the `while` loop:

```
while (token_arr != NULL)
{
   printf("tokens--%s\n",token_arr);

   sprintf(temp,"%d",strlen(token_arr));

   // +3 -> two spaces and the terminating null character.
   length = length + strlen(token_arr) + strlen(temp) + 3;

   if ( *final_buff == NULL )
   {
      // No need to use length*sizeof(char). sizeof(char) is 
      // guaranteed to be 1
      *final_buff = malloc(length);
      (*final_buff)[0] = '\0';
   }
   else
   {
      *final_buff = realloc(*final_buff,(length));/*allocate memory for the buffer*/
   }

   if (NULL == *final_buff)
   {
      printf("token memory allocation error\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   strcat(*final_buff,token_arr); /*concatinate the token to buffer*/
   strcat(*final_buff," ");
   strcat(*final_buff,temp);      /*concatinate buffer with string length */
   strcat(*final_buff," ");
   token_arr = strtok(NULL , ",");/*read next token */
}
```

Comment: Note that `realloc(0, length)` is the same as `malloc(length)`.  Setting the null terminator is important.

Comment: This solution is OK. Please note it requries *final_buff to be NULL upon entry. This is a requirement to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

`*final_buff` should *always* be null-terminated.
When it is allocated for the first time with `realloc`, it may not be null-terminated. You are writing with `strcat` to it, which requires the buffer to be already null-terminated.

In `main`, you could write

```
char *final_buff = malloc(sizeof(char));  // allocate 1 char
// todo: error checking
*final_buff = 0;  // null-terminate
data_token(databuf,&final_buff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf()` if you want to convert a value to a string and need to make sure you don't overflow a buffer.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

> **Return value**
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings).
>
> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size
>   bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')). If the output was
>   truncated due to this limit then the return value is the number of
>   characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been
>   written to the final string if enough space had been available. Thus,
>   a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated.
>   (See also below under NOTES.)
>
> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.

Comment: In the OP's case the it would be sufficient if the buffer provided was larger enough to hold the decimal ASCII representation of the the maximum value fitting into a `size_t`. Here there is no need to use `snprintf()` then.

Comment: Well, his 10 isn't big enough then.  And what if he decides to change his representation to octal or binary for some reason?

Comment: For the former I fully agree, for the latter the code needs to be adjusted.. Which might be acceptable. In any case the buffer's maximum size necessary **is** known at compile time, so no run-time checks are necessary.  Moreover just cutting the number to be "printed" because the buffer is to small, without even logging an error or aborting the whole operation does not seem to be appropriate.

Comment: The buffer size is known at compile time but it's not a fixed value unless you want to use `#ifdef()/#elif/#else` preprocessor directives covering all possible (and platform dependent) variable sizes - because simply changing one compiler flag - e.g. `gcc -m64 ...` - can directly affect your very own example.  If `snprintf()` would truncate the output string, **not** using `snprintf()` would result in buffer overrun - hardly an improvement.  Since in the case of truncation `snprintf()` returns the size necessary to hold a full conversion, just rerun the conversion with a big-enough buffer.